# If I burn a log & contain all the matter, will the burned log weigh $E/c^2$ less than the unburned log, with $E$ being the energy from light & heat?

Tags: energy-conservation, physical-chemistry, mass-energy, matter, combustion

I understand that the change in weight would be tiny even to a physicist and nothing for any practical purpose. I am also not talking about smoke and water vapor. I am only referring to energy given off as heat and light leaving the closed system.

As a follow up, would the energy have weight equal to the difference if it exists? If the heat and light were also contained would the weight be exactly the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conversion of mass to energy in chemical/nuclear reactions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11449/)

Comment: Sure. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/614808/123208

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. It's best to ask about mass rather than weight in this context.